# Query the sum of a value in a many-to-many relation

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jpa

My model is the following:

```
table video:
int id (PK)
int views

table tag:
int id (PK)

table video_tag:
int id (PK)
int video_id (FK to video.id)
int tag_id (FK to tag.id)
```

The model describes a *many-to-many* relationship between tags and videos. A video can have multiple tags describing its content. It also has a field with the number of views. The same tag can also refer to multiple videos.

I would like to build a query (preferably in *JPA/JPQL/HQL*, but *SQL* will do as well) that returns all the tags ordered by the sum of the views the videos they refer to have.

For example: two videos videoA and videoB both have the tag Foo. VideoA has 2 views, videoB has 3 views. The number to sort on for tag Foo is 5.

Here are two attempts using JPA:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Tag t, SUM(v.views) as viewCount FROM Video v WHERE t MEMBER OF v.tags ORDER BY viewCount DESC")
@Query("SELECT t FROM (SELECT t, SUM(v.views) as viewCount FROM Tag t, Video v WHERE t MEMBER OF v.tags) ORDER BY viewCount DESC")
```

Attempt using SQL:

```
select t.id, sum(v.views) from tag t, video v where t.id in (select vt.tag_id from video_tag vt where vt.tag_id=t.id and vt.video_id=v.id)
```

Comment: DownVoted because it shows no efforts at all. Just the requirement.

Comment: I added two attempts I made restricting the query to JPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `join` between the three tables and a `group by` should work:

```
select t.id, t.label, sum(views)
from video_tag as vt
inner join video as v on v.id = vt.video_id
inner join tag as t on t.id = vt.tag_id
group by t.id, t.label
;
```

See it running here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e366a0/1

Comment: I also found the JPA query that does the same thing (even shorter :) )  

SELECT t FROM Tag t JOIN FETCH t.videos v GROUP BY t ORDER BY SUM(v.views) DESC